# Why is this pushdown automaton for some palindromes right?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata, correctness-proof

$B = \{w \in \{0,1\}^* | w^R = w, w \text{ length is odd} \}$

Solution:

[image]

For example: $111$ should be accepted

steps are

$q_1 \to q_2$ stack: [$\$$]

$q_2 \to q_2$ stack: $[\$, 1, 1]$ (using up $11$ only having a single $1$ left)

$q_2 \to q_3$ stack: $[\$, 1, 1]$ (no change except we lost our final $1$)

$q_3 \to$ (no strings left to use)

I'm confused understanding this

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDAs are *nondeterministic*. Although you have found a valid computation which does not lead to an accept state, a PDA is said to *accept* its input if there is *some* valid computation which does lead to an accept state.

In this case (input $111$), an accepting computation is:

1. $q_1 \to q_2$, stack: $[\$]$
2. $q_2 \to q_2$, stack: $[\$, 1]$
3. $q_2 \to q_3$, stack: $[\$, 1]$
4. $q_3 \to q_3$, stack: $[\$]$
5. $q_3 \to q_4$, stack: $[]$

Answer (score 0):

A PDA is non-deterministic. Nondeterministic automata accept a string w if any path along which w might be processed results in w's being accepted. so the PDA will try all paths and only accept the string if one of these paths landed in an accept state.

**For a detailed explanation check these links:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214674/how-does-a-pushdown-automaton-know-how-to-read-a-palindrome?rq=1

Neso academy- Pushdown Automata Example (Even Palindrome) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHj2WI1Rrl4&list=PLBlnK6fEyqRgp46KUv4ZY69yXmpwKOIev&index=82&app=desktop